# Modify my SQL Server query -- returns too many rows sometimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, querying

I need to update the following query so that it only returns *one* child record (remittance) per parent (claim).

Table Remit_To_Activate contains exactly one date/timestamp per claim, which is what I wanted.

But when I join the full Remittance table to it, since some claims have multiple remittances with the same date/timestamps, the outermost query returns more than 1 row per claim for those claim IDs.

```
SELECT * FROM REMITTANCE 
WHERE BILLED_AMOUNT>0 AND ACTIVE=0 
AND REMITTANCE_UUID IN ( 
  SELECT REMITTANCE_UUID FROM Claims_Group2 G2
  INNER JOIN Remit_To_Activate t ON (
    (t.ClaimID = G2.CLAIM_ID) AND 
    (t.DATE_OF_LATEST_REGULAR_REMIT = G2.CREATE_DATETIME)
)
  where ACTIVE=0 and BILLED_AMOUNT>0
)
```

I believe the problem would be resolved if I included REMITTANCE_UUID as a column in Remit_To_Activate.  That's the REAL issue.  This is how I created the Remit_To_Activate table (trying to get the most recent remittance for a claim):

```
SELECT MAX(create_datetime) as DATE_OF_LATEST_REMIT,
MAX(claim_id) AS ClaimID,
INTO Latest_Remit_To_Activate 
FROM Claims_Group2
WHERE BILLED_AMOUNT>0
GROUP BY Claim_ID 
ORDER BY Claim_ID
```

Claims_Group2 contains these fields:
  REMITTANCE_UUID,
  CLAIM_ID,
  BILLED_AMOUNT,
  CREATE_DATETIME

Here are the 2 rows that are currently giving me the problem--they're both remitts for the SAME CLAIM, with the SAME TIMESTAMP.  I only want one of them in the Remits_To_Activate table, so only ONE remittance will be "activated" per Claim:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIGUJ.png)

Comment: When you do so, please also clarify whether you're asking how to rewrite your query or how to modify your database to support a suitable query.  If the former, then we are indeed missing essential information: how to identify which remittance it is that you want to return for each claim.  Either way, we probably need more information about the current database structure.

Comment: Thank you, John.  I'm asking for help in rewriting a query.  I believe the 2nd query, the one I just added to my original post (instead of putting it as a comment) is the issue.   

In my mind, if I can create a temp table containing the Claim ID, Remittance UUID, and timestamp of the *most recent remittance* for each claim, that's all I need.  Then I can just join to the temp table on REMITTANCE_UUID in my final query (to find the ones to activate).

Comment: That does provide somewhat more information about your database structure.  You apparently want the latest remittance for each claim, but you've already identified an essential problem with that: for some claims, the data do not uniquely identify a single latest remittance.  So by what logic should one particular remittance be chosen from among multiple "latest" remittances for a given claim?

Comment: It doesn't matter--if they all have the same timestamp, any of the remittances for a claim will do.  If I could figure out how to include the REMITTANCE_UUID in the table created in 2nd query above, that *would* make the rows unique in that table.  But I don't know how to choose the UUID off the row whose timestamp I'm getting.

Comment: In that case, relational algebra has no solution for you, but your particular DBMS may have something that will help.  So which DBMS is that?

Comment: I don't think I've made my question clear.  I just need to know how to get the REMITTANCE_UUID off the row whose timestamp is most recent so I can include it as a field when I'm creating the "Remits_To_Activate" table.  Then the rows in that table *will* be unique--problem solved.  (I'm trying to figure out how to give you a screenshot of the data I'm selecting from ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query like this:

```
SELECT
  p.*, latest_remit.DATE_OF_LATEST_REMIT
FROM
  Remittance AS p inner join
(SELECT MAX(create_datetime) as DATE_OF_LATEST_REMIT,
claim_id,
FROM Claims_Group2
WHERE BILLED_AMOUNT>0
GROUP BY Claim_ID 
ORDER BY Claim_ID) as latest_remit
on latest_remit.claim_id = p.claim_id;
```

This will give you only one row. Untested (so please run and make changes).

Comment: I don't think so.  In the first place `top` is not universally supported.  In the second place, that yields a one-row table.  The OP needs one row *per `ClaimID`*.  However, if the OP's DBMS happens to be one of those that supports `top`, then it should be possible to use that (differently) to create a solution.  This is among the reasons why I asked them about their DBMS.

Comment: he is saying in post sql server

Comment: Where do you see that?  I must be missing it.

Comment: see the title - "Modify my SQL Server query — returns too many rows sometimes"

Answer (score 0):

Without having more information on the structure of your database -- especially the structure of `Claims_Group2` and `REMITTANCE`, and the relationship between them, it's not really possible to advise you on how to introduce a remittance UUID into `DATE_OF_LATEST_REMIT`.

Since you are using SQL Server, however, it *is* possible to use a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to introduce a synthetic means to choose among remittances having the same timestamp. For example, it looks like you could approach the problem something like this:

```
select *
from (
  select
    r.*,
    row_number() over (partition by cg2.claim_id order by cg2.create_datetime desc) as rn
  from
    remittance r
    join claims_group2 cg2
      on r.remittance_uuid = cg2.remittance_uuid
  where
    r.active = 0 
    and r.billed_amount > 0
    and cg2.active = 0
    and cg2.billed_amount > 0
  ) t
where t.rn = 1
```

Note that that that does not depend on your `DATE_OF_LATEST_REMIT` table at all, it having been subsumed into the inline view.  Note also that this will introduce one extra column into your results, though you could avoid that by enumerating the columns of table `remittance` in the outer `select` clause.

It also seems odd to be filtering on two sets of `active` and `billed_amount` columns, but that appears to follow from what you were doing in your original queries.  In that vein, I urge you to check the results carefully, as lifting the filter conditions on `cg2` columns up to the level of the join to `remittance` yields a result that may return rows that the original query did not (but never more than one per `claim_id`).

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker offered me this elegant demonstration of a solution.  I'd never used "over" or "partition" before.  Works great!  Thank you John and Gaurasvsa for your input.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') is not null
drop table #t

select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CLAIM_ID order by CLAIM_ID) as ROW_NUM
into #t
from 
(
    select '2018-08-15 13:07:50.933' as CREATE_DATE, 1 as CLAIM_ID, NEWID() as 
    REMIT_UUID
    union select '2018-08-15 13:07:50.933', 1, NEWID()
    union select '2017-12-31 10:00:00.000', 2, NEWID()
) x 

select * 
from #t
order by CLAIM_ID, ROW_NUM

select CREATE_DATE, MAX(CLAIM_ID), MAX(REMIT_UUID)
from #t
where ROW_NUM = 1
group by CREATE_DATE
```